# Do I lose points on my Luxembourg license when fined in Belgium, France, Netherlands or Germany?

Tags: europe, eu, driving-licenses, luxembourg

The Luxembourg driver's license has a point system where points are deducted after an offense depending on the [severity](https://www.angloinfo.com/how-to/luxembourg/transport/driving-licences/licence-points-system).

I am wondering whether this also applies when I speed in Belgium, France, Netherlands or Germany.

Is there a source where I can find the current agreements between these countries? I know that there is one between France and Luxembourg from a colleague (he has a French license and his points got deducted after a violation in Luxembourg). I wonder if this holds also the other way around and what the status of agreements is with the other countries mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Each country has its own point system, they exist independent from each other. However, further agreements between countries may exist.

For offenses in Germany, you only ever get "German points" but if you reach the limit, German officials will seize your Luxembourgish license if you lived in Germany. If you lived outside Germany, they will put a sticker in your license saying  you are banned from driving on German roads and will also put you into a database of people who are banned.

Comment: Thanks. How about Belgium and France having a luxe license?

Comment: Someone else has to answer that.